# Excel VBA function using a "FOR" loop to calculate multiple columns of data and display it in a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform that I want to use to calculate rates and concentrations for 8 separate chemicals. The userform that I built has 3 different columns with 8 rows in each column. the first column is a combobox that contains the overall concentration of the chemical, the second and third columns are labels which I would like to display a particular value based on the overall concentration and data that I have defined elsewhere in the userform. I have written the code for the first row of chemical data as this:

```
'chemical calculator
If CC1.Value = "" Or CC1.Value = 0 Then
    CRb1.Visible = False
    CCb1.Visible = False
Else
    CRb1.Visible = True
    CCb1.Visible = True
    CRb1.Caption = Round((cClean * 0.042 * CC1.Value), 2)
    CCb1.Caption = Round((CRb1.Caption / ((cClean - PSrate) * 0.042)), 2)
End If
```

CC1 is the combobox in column 1 row 1
CCb1 is the label in column 2 row 1
CRb1 is the label in column 3 row 1

I have standardized the names of all the comboboxes and labels only varying the number based on which row they are in.

The above code works fine and I know I could very well copy it 8 times and change the numbers but in the interest of learning something new and keeping it easy to read I'd like to find out how to do this using a "FOR"(?) loop, but I'm fairly new to programming and might be missing something. I've tried the following:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 8
    Dim Conc As String
        Conc = "CC" & i & ".Value"
    Dim bConcVis As String
        bConcVis = "CCb" & i & ".Visible"
    Dim bConcCap As String
        bConcCap = "CCb" & i & ".Caption"
    Dim bRateVis As String
        bRateVis = "CRb" & i & ".Visible"
    Dim bRateCap As String
        bRateCap = "CRb" & i & ".Caption"

    If Conc = "" Or Conc = 0 Then
        bRateVis = False
        bConcVis = False
    Else
        bRateVis = True
        bConcVis = True
        bRateCap = Round((cClean * 0.042 * CC1.Value), 2)
        bConcCap = Round((bRateCap / ((cClean - PSrate) * 0.042)), 2)
    End If
Next i
```

this results in a runtime error '13' Type mismatch and highlights the conditional portion of my IF statement. I can (try to) provide more info if needed, but if anyone has ideas I'd be very interested to hear them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want Conc = "0". Conc has been dim'd as a string. You can't compare it to a numeric value.

Comment: That solves the type mismatch for that line, ends up giving me the same error for the last two lines of code in the "ELSE" portion. I'm guessing it's the same issue having dim'd bRateCap and bConcCap as strings but using a formula to determine a numeric value for them. Any ideas on ways to "convert" those?

Comment: If they are meant to be numbers, declare them as numeric values. Alternatively, make a new variable to hold it when it's number.

Comment: Your using a string that looks like it should be a string in '`bRateCap = "CRb" & i & ".Caption"` bRateCap is not a number but it's in your formula `Round((bRateCap / ((cClean - PSrate) * 0.042)), 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, I am guessing you are trying to grab a value from combobox **CC1**?

If that's the case, try **Controls**

```
UserForm1.Controls("CC" & i).Value
```

Because what you are doing in your code is that

you are just setting **Conc** to get value **"CC1.Value"**

And If statement will check if "CC1.Value" = 0, instead of grabbing the value from combobox **CC1** and comparing it to 0

Comment: Solves the problem, thanks to everyone for the help! this'll definitely come in handy in the future as well!